# How can I fix - Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Action'

Tags: angular, dictionary, ionic-framework, angularfire2

The code snippets below are part of my ionic3/angularfire2 project.  It connects to a Firestore DB - and should return a snapshot observable of a document.

From my web research, I can see that others have used similar syntax - I cannot find solution to mine

```
// (all other imports are fine)

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

in the constructor, I inject ...

```
private db: AngularFirestore
```

the code below has an error (i am seriously unhappy)

```
// customerRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>;
this.customerRef = this.db.doc(`customers/${k}`);

// cust: Observable<Customer>;
this.cust = this.customerRef.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
  return actions.map(action => {
    const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Customer;
    const id = action.payload.doc.id;
    console.log('>>>>', { id, ...data });
    return { id, ...data };
  });
});
```

I get the following error

```
Typescript Error
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Action<DocumentSnapshot>'.
```

I have other parts of the project that retrieve observable of collection of some documents (.valueChanges) - and they work just fine.

Please help.  (if I have missed to describe something, I apologize - and will do if somebody points it out - tried to focus on the code with error)

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.5
Node: 6.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.0.3

    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "promise-polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
```

Comment: You might want to provide the type to actions. If you are aware about the keys than use interface to declare the type of actions Array else please check by providing it a type as any. I hope it might helps.

Comment: Ajay - first let me say - Waaw!  That error has gone - thanks a lot.  Now I have "actions.map is not a function" error.  At least, the one that was more frustrating is gone!  The "any" worked - not the type/interface

Comment: Thanks for the awesome appreciation. You might have to declare the type for customerRef and snapshotChanges for actions to work with types. **any** might be a **immediate solution** but declaring a **specific type** is the **right** way. Thanks for the appreciation.

Comment: Hi @GeoffKabule how did you fix your issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is the confusion of how snapshotChanges() behaves when dealing with a document or a collection of documents.

The code you used is fine for a collection of documents, but when dealing with documents it changes slightly.

Try this.

```
// customerRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>;
this.customerRef = this.db.doc(`customers/${k}`);

// cust: Observable<Customer>;
this.cust = this.customerRef.snapshotChanges().map(action => {
  const data = action.payload.data() as Customer;
  const id = action.payload.id;
  return { id, ...data };
});
```

#### And for Angular 6+ that uses newer rxjs

```
// customerRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<Customer>;
this.customerRef = this.db.doc(`customers/${k}`);

// cust: Observable<Customer>;
this.cust = this.customerRef.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(action => {
  const data = action.payload.data() as Customer;
  const id = action.payload.id;
  return { id, ...data };
}));
```

Comment: what is the library? because there are 3 to import jeje for the map of the pipe for angular 6+

Comment: @M.Mariscal `map` in this context is from RxJS. But this post is from 2018, so maybe there has been changes to these APIs specially angularfire

Comment: Thank you, at the end i fixed it on other way!